# How can I change keyboard shortcuts for Evince (and other GNOME programs)?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, evince

Is there a way to customize keyboard shortcuts for Evince, the GNOME document viewer?

Comment: Have you tried these?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/136062/permanent-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince-document-viewer

https://askubuntu.com/questions/555401/how-to-customize-add-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince/899956#899956

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the source code of evince (source code provided by Debian 9.9, evince 3.22.1) and since every shortcuts are written "as-is" in internationalization files (`.po`), i guess they are hardcoded.

For example:

```
help/fr/fr.po:msgid "<keyseq><key>Ctrl</key><key>R</key></keyseq>"
help/fr/fr.po:msgstr "<keyseq><key>Ctrl</key><key>R</key></keyseq>"
```

I'm trying to dig more, but the way evince manage shortcut is quite ... strange :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit them in the source code, [where they are defined](https://github.com/GNOME/evince/blob/6906067ee8f59bc8d20deb72e4aec65c8f4cbece/shell/ev-application.c#L942), and rebuild the package:

In theory, evince should read the accels file at [init time](https://github.com/GNOME/evince/blob/6906067ee8f59bc8d20deb72e4aec65c8f4cbece/shell/ev-application.c#L1124) and merge with the ones it has, so you can also change the accels file, in ~/.config/evince/accels. Keep in mind that it gets overwritten if there are syntax errors.

Comment: I don't have a file at ~/.config/evince/accels. Is there supposed to be something there?

Comment: It might be distribution/window manager dependent. It is there in Debian 9 + Xfce4. It is created automatically by evince if it does not exist.

Comment: Do I have to copy it over from some place in the filesystem, like `/usr/...evince`? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: It should be there. What is your system, its version and the the Evince version?

Comment: Evince 3.34.1 on Manjaro, with all the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

I resigned to customize keyboard shortcut for Gnome Program.
I can not use accels file.
I wrote patch for source code in old by portage.
However, I gave up because the source code changes frequently.

In now, I use [mooz/xkeysnail: Yet another keyboard remapping tool for X environment](https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail).

I write config file.

```py
define_keymap(re.compile("Evince"), {
    # t
    K("k"): K("r"),
}, "Evince")
```

One caution is required, and if you touch a key without a modifier key, it will be converted when you enter it in the search form.